# Request time out from AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create app with `serverless` framework.

Every functions works fine on my local machine.

But remote machine(Lambda) gives to below error message. (This take a 30sec)

```
{
    "message": "Endpoint request timed out"
}
```

Code size is `37.5 MB`, and instance memory size is `3008 MB`.

Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you give some more info? How is the lambda triggered? When does this error occur? Maybe you are trying to make a request from lambda to your LAN and this is not allowed?

Comment: can you share the code over github or here, for overview .. but remove sensitive information from that ..

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problems with set to `callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false`.

By default calling the callback() function in a NodeJS Lambda function does not end the function execution. It will continue running until the event loop is empty. A common issue with NodeJS Lambda functions continuing to run after callback is called occurs when you are holding on to open database connections. You haven't posted any code, so I can't give specific recommendations, but you would need to determine if you are leaving database connections open in your code or something similar.

Here's what the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html) says about the behavior of callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop:

> **callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop**
>
> The default value is true. This property is useful only to modify the
>   default behavior of the callback. By default, the callback will wait
>   until the Node.js runtime event loop is empty before freezing the
>   process and returning the results to the caller. You can set this
>   property to false to request AWS Lambda to freeze the process soon
>   after the callback is called, even if there are events in the event
>   loop. AWS Lambda will freeze the process, any state data and the
>   events in the Node.js event loop (any remaining events in the event
>   loop processed when the Lambda function is called next and if AWS
>   Lambda chooses to use the frozen process). For more information about
>   callback, [see Using the Callback Parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html#nodejs-prog-model-handler-callback).